# Get the first 100 records in a list

Tags: apex

Say i got a list

```
list<account> mylist = [select name from account];
```

what is the best way to get first 100 records in this list.

I mean convert mylist to mylist with first 100 records

Comment: May be worth specifying if your list will always be SOQL based or if you're curious about pure list apex possibilities.

Comment: Yes my list will be always based on SOQL.I actually need to display a message if my SOQL query returns more than 100 records.So i thought i cannot apply limit on SOQl.But need to get everything and then ,display message and get first 100records

Comment: It's not really advised to query without selective criteria or limit clause. Maybe you can abstract your message thing by first doing a separate "select count(id) from account" query  and base your message on that.

Comment: there is a selective criteria..but yeah no limit.may be i can apply a limit of 101 to reduce no.of records coming back..but my message,is something that is displayed along with this 100 records.So even if do count(id) again i need to write soql for getting those records

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could have queried the list that way originally:

```
account[] mylist = [select id,name from account limit 100];
```

Or, you could copy them one at a time:

```
account[] mylist2 = new account[0];
integer counter = 0;
while(counter<100 && counter<mylist.size()) {
    mylist2.add(mylist[counter++]);
}
```

**Update** To find out if there are more records than can be displayed at once, set your limit one higher, and check for the presence of the max value:

```
account[] mylist = [select id,name from account limit 101];
if(mylist.size()==101) {
    mylist.remove(101);
    apexpages.addmessage(new apexpages.message(apexpages.severity.info,'More than 100 results found. Please narrow your search criteria.'));
}
```

Comment: In addition: If size() would only be a little over 100, you could also remove some items which may be marginally faster for small numbers(like 100).

Comment: my list will be always based on SOQL.I actually need to display a message if my SOQL query returns more than 100 records.So i thought i cannot apply limit on SOQl.But need to get everything and then ,display message and get first 100records

Comment: Updated answer to include a way you might check for more than 100 records using `LIMIT`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `limit` in SOQL statements:

```
list<account> mylist = [select name from account limit 100];
```

Remember to order it so that your list is deterministic.

Comment: my list will be always based on SOQL.I actually need to display a message if my SOQL query returns more than 100 records.So i thought i cannot apply limit on SOQl.But need to get everything and then ,display message and get first 100records